# Is there a way to insert Checkbox and Combobox in Sidebar in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5, sidebar, sap-fiori, ui5-tooling

I have created a tnt Sidebar and want to insert Checkboxes and Combobox in it.

This should be the result:

[image]

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

So the NavigationItems should be replaced by Checkboxes. f.E. sap.m.CheckBox

```
 <content>
        <tnt:ToolPage>
            <tnt:sideContent>
                <tnt:SideNavigation  id="sideNavigation" selectedKey="subItem3">
                    <tnt:NavigationList>
                        <tnt:NavigationListItem text="Item 1" icon="sap-icon://employee">
                            <tnt:NavigationListItem  text="Sub Item 1" >
                            </tnt:NavigationListItem>
                            <tnt:NavigationListItem text="Sub Item 2" />
                            <tnt:NavigationListItem text="Sub Item 3" id="subItem3" key="subItem3" />
                            <tnt:NavigationListItem text="Sub Item 4" />
                        </tnt:NavigationListItem>
                        <tnt:NavigationListItem text="Item 2" icon="sap-icon://building">
                            <tnt:NavigationListItem text="Sub Item 1" />
                            <tnt:NavigationListItem text="Sub Item 2" />
                            <tnt:NavigationListItem text="Sub Item 3" />
                            <tnt:NavigationListItem text="Sub Item 4" />
                        </tnt:NavigationListItem>
                    </tnt:NavigationList>
```

I tried to insert a sap.m.CheckBox instead of a normal NavigationListItem but then I get an error, that the "CheckBox" class is under the "items" aggregation and must match the "NavigationListItem" type.

I know Fiori/UI5 is limited somehow and you shouldn't mix up too much different namespaces, but is there some workaround?

Kind regards
Sebastian

Comment: It is possible, but not without some effort. The `NavigationList` accepts only `NavigationListItem`s, but the trick is, you can extend this class with your own, add an aggregated control and render it.

Comment: @fmi21Okay thank you. Could you provide me some more informations or links how to do that ?

Comment: Something like [this](https://pastebin.com/gKAQ5qv6). This is only a starting point, as said it is a bit of an effort but is the most serious option IMO, not relying on CSS and reusing the native `sap.m.NativeList` side panel, if you are serious about implementing this. I've personally implemented a control following this plan, for a `sap.m.Button` inside `sap.m.IconTabBar` [here](https://pastebin.com/QxU5gL7z). The missing methods I've copied over from the source. It's far from perfect, we later abandoned it due to the maintenance effort required, but can still serve you as guidance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but maybe creating a List or TreeList with a CustomListItem would help you more.
You can put it into a SplitApp and have a "Navigation like" Panel too, but fully customizable.